# Class-function that returns a struct which is a private member of that class

Tags: c++

```
class Tree {
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node *left,*right;
        Node(int v, Node *n = NULL):data(v),left(n),right(n) {}
    };
    Node *root; 
    int size;
public :
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    struct Node* GetRoot();
```

Thats my .h file.When I write the following on the source file :

```
struct Node* Tree::GetRoot() {
      return root;
}
```

I get the following warnings from Eclipse :

-Member declaration not found

Any ideas?I feel like a tried everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your definition you need to specify the scope of the private struct:

```
struct Tree::Node* Tree::GetRoot() {
    // ^^^^^^
    return root;
}
```

---

As others pointed out in comments, it's noteworthy that a client calling this function cannot access the `Tree::Node` type directly, but only using the `auto` keyword:

```
Tree t;
auto root = t.GetRoot();

// pass the obtained value back
t.DoSomethingWithRoot(root);
```

Comment: @juanchopanza Can be used with `auto` by clients IIRC.

Comment: To pile-on, the error is because the compiler doesn't know what Node is unless you scope it to the Tree class. So you must declare that you are returning a Node thing that can be found inside the Tree class.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how can one use the OP's .h file prior to c++11's auto keyword?

Comment: @ZivS You cannot IIRC, maybe using a `public` `typedef`.

Comment: @ZivS You still can say stuff such as `t.GetRoot().data` for example.